# Add active class on keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onkeydown

Hi I am new to stack overflow and jquery and this is my first question.

I would like to add and remove a active class to multiple divs with the same class on an keydown event and trigger a click function to active class.

the html code is something like this

```
 <div id="playbar_wrapper">
    <div id="standard_buttons" tabindex='0'>
    <div class="button_wrapper"><div onclick= "rwdButton()" id="prev"  class="button"><img src="prev.png"  alt="Previous Item"/></div></div>
    <div class="button_wrapper"><div onclick= "stopButton()" id="stop"  class="button"><img src="stop.png"  alt="Stop"/></div></div>
    <div class="button_wrapper active"><div onclick= "playButton()" id="play"  class="button"><img src="play.png"  alt="Play"/></div></div>
    <div class="button_wrapper"><div onclick= "pauseButton()" id="pause" class="button"><img src="pause.png" alt="Pause"/></div></div>
   <div class="button_wrapper"><div onclick= "fwdButton()" id="next"  class="button"><img src="next.png"  alt="Next Item"/></div></div>                 
</div>
</div>
```

And javascipt code is as follows:
the keypress function:

```
KeypressFunctions[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] = nextButton; 

function nextButton(){
  var currentArticle = 
$('.active').removeClass('active').next('.button_wrapper');

currentArticle= currentArticle.length > 0 ?  currentArticle : 
$('#standard_buttons div:eq(0)');
     currentArticle.addClass('active').children('.button').click(); 

}
```

The click function works on the two divs at the same time.
Sorry for not being clear enough. But any help would be really great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and share it here.

Comment: _“the html code is something like this”_ - like what? Please provide a [mcve]. And also go read [ask] - and then describe what _specifically_ your problem is; right now that is rather unclear.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yjfq7d1a/1/                                                                                            Here is a fiddle I could create and sorry for the inconvenience. Here I would like to know how to add active class to the next divs with the same class and remove the active class from the previous div.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confuse... maybe you want something arround this?

```
$( "#standard_buttons div:eq(0)" ).keydown(function() {
  $( "#standard_buttons div:eq(0)").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I exactly need. :)